# How do I dynamically load a C++ AMP kernel at runtime?

Tags: gpu, gpgpu, c++-amp

In CUDA, you can create a kernel at runtime, compile it into PTX and load it then and there. How can I do the same thing in C++ AMP?

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no way to do this with C++ AMP. It might be possible using the underlying DirectCompute APIs, rather than the C++AMP ones.

I'd be interested to know what problem you are trying to solve that needs kernel generation at runtime.